# Extract string from file and assign to variable using scripting in Bash

Tags: bash

Currently I need to extract a number from a line in a file, add +1 to that number write it over the previous number in the same file using Bash. So my line looks something like this :

```
<Server port="8080" ... >
```

and I want to make it `<Server port="8081" ... >`

I know that using the sed - command I can find the "8080" and replace it with something, I just dont know how to actually get the 8080 and turn it into a 8081.
How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You grep the value using sed (or awk), you do a normal addition in you bash script, you replace the line with sed (or awk). Check this link for sed http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/09/unix-sed-tutorial-replace-text-inside-a-file-using-substitute-command/ and this one for doing calculations in bash https://www.shell-tips.com/2010/06/14/performing-math-calculation-in-bash/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to do addition, `awk` is a better tool than `sed`.

Consider the file:

```
$ cat file
<Server port="8080" ... >
```

We can increment the port number like this:

```
$ awk -F\" '/<Server/{$2++} 1' file
<Server port= 8081  ... >
```

This was designed to work with the sample input that you provided.

#### How it works

- `-F\"`

  Set the field separator to `"`.  With this as the field separator, the port number is its own field.
- `/<Server/`

  Select only line containing the word `Server`.
- `{$2++}`

  For those selected lines, increment the second field by one.
- `1`

  This is awk's cryptic shorthand for "print all lines."

Comment: Hadn't used awk before. Thanks a lot - great explanation.